# Delay a PyQT update function every time the array swapped

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt, pyqt6

What occurs is that it waits 3 seconds then proceeds to update the array all at once. in bubbleSort trying to use QTimer. I would like it everytime it swaps to wait 3 seconds.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt,QRect,QTimer
import random
import time
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.values = random.sample(range(10, 100), 20)
        self.h = 50
        self.w = len(self.values)*self.h
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, self.w, self.h)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drawing text')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        i=0
        for x in self.values:
            rect = QRect(i,0,50,50)
            qp.drawRect(rect)
            qp.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, str(x))
            i+=50
        qp.end()
        self.bubbleSort()    
        
    def bubbleSort(self):
        n = len(self.values)
        swapped = False
        for i in range(n-1):
            for j in range(0, n-i-1):
                if self.values[j] > self.values[j + 1]:
                    swapped = True
                    self.values[j],  self.values[j + 1] =  self.values[j + 1], self.values[j]
                    QTimer.singleShot(3000,self.RefreshData)

            if not swapped:
                return

    def RefreshData(self):
        self.update()
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem is simple. It is with this line `if not swapped: return`. Just take out the `not` from the if-statement and it should work: `if swapped: return`.

Comment: I tested it using PySide2.

Comment: Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: 1. The `if swapped` suggested above is actually really unnecessary: since you're already comparing the `values`, just `break` or `return` in that block; 2. be very careful with `singleShot` timers, as they could overlap themselves because they are static functions that always start a ***new*** timer whenever called. Instead, create a *persistent* QTimer (with the [`singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop) property set to `True`) and restart it whenever necessary.

Comment: Also, I get the point of using it for tests, but calling `bubleSort` from `paintEvent` can easily create lots of single shots at once and execute all bubblesort steps instantly. One way to reproduce this problem is when you try to resize the window. `paintEvent` will be fired a lot of times all at once when trying to redraw the widget.